# authentication header vs query parameter in google cloud endpoints

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-endpoints

I have tried everything, yet I cannot access my API using google cloud endpoints using a `Authentication:Bearer` header. According to [Cloud Endpoints Docs](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users):

> When you send a request using an authentication token, for security reasons, we recommend that you put the token in the Authorization:Bearer header.

it also says:

> If you cannot use the header when sending the request, you can put the authentication token in a query parameter called access_token.

I can perfectly access the API using `access_token=" +idToken` in my URL. However, when I try to send an HTTP request with the Authentication header like this:

```
const url =
        "https://<PROJECTNAME>.appspot.com/getbalance";
    axios
        .get(url,{headers:{'Authentication':'Bearer '+idToken}})
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

I get this error:

```
JWT validation failed: Missing or invalid credentials
```

Is sending the token in a query parameter as safe as sending it in the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code example shows you setting an Auth**entication** header, not an Auth**orization** header. You should not typically use a query parameter as it will likely get logged in Cloud Console.

Comment: so whats the downside of getting logged in there?

Comment: I would argue that it's a very lax security practice to allow auth tokens to be logged.

Answer (score 0):

When using "Authorization: Bearer ", you would need to use an access token obtained through OAuth 2.0 authentication.

This can be illustrated if you use the [Oauth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) agains any of the Google APIs.

Keep in mind that if you want to access your Firebase database using the Oauth Playground, you would need to configure the client ID and client Secret of your Firebase project on the gear icon at the top right of the playground screen. 
Also make sure to use these scopes:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database

After completing all the steps, you will be able to make a REST request using the authorization header with the obtained access token.

Comment: I am asking the difference between sending the token through the header versus sending it in the url